# Android Studio - Error: Android Source Generator: Android SDK is not specifed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting "Error: Android Source Generator:[app_name] Android SDK is not specifed" in Android Studio while trying to Build Project.

I have Android Studio 1.0.2 RC4 version.

What have been done:

- SDK installed ith SDK Manager
- Project Structure -> SDK; I have added there minimum and target SDK as well
- updated build.gradle

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.byoutline.pinafood"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.4.+'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project Structure->SDK Location` and make sure the path is set correctly.

Comment: It is. I checked it million times - I know it seems easy, but it just don't work and I'm getting minuses here for nothing...

Comment: What about your local.properties file.  Is that set up correctly?

Comment: You should have sdk.dir=C\:/sdk-path in there.

Comment: I have: sdk.dir=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\sdk (not sure about double slashes, but folder is where sdk's lies)

Comment: Can you do a gradle build at all?  Or does it bomb when you actually compile?

Comment: Build -> 'Compile' button is inactive. I can't even compile. When I do Build -> 'Make project' then previously mentioned error appears.

Comment: Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3 sec;
Information:1 error;
Information:0 warnings;
Error:Android Source Generator: [pinafood] Android SDK is not specified;

Comment: What about your build.gradle file?  You can change from the "build.gradle" file the line:

compileSdkVersion 18
to the sdk that you want to be used.

Comment: One more question, how did you originally start the project?  Did you import from an Eclipse project or is this a brand new one?

Comment: What about your build.gradle file in your app directory?

Comment: I looked at that project on github and it is calling for Android SDK 20?  Do you have that installed on android studio?

Comment: Yes, but I changed targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 21

Comment: Can you start a clean project then import the files one at a time (a pain, I know)?

Comment: You're sure your <project name>/app/build.gradle file is correct?  You posted the one in your <project name>/build.gradle folder.

Comment: This probably won't help but give it a shot, add:  apply plugin: 'android'

Comment: Can you create a "hello world" program?  If you can, you can start with a fresh project then add files one by one to it to recreate what you saw on github.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to upated build:gradle to 1.0.0 (only by changing those number in build.gradle file and change from runProguard to minifyEnabled.